# Should I clean (how?) old drywall before applying mud?

Tags: drywall, cleaning, drywall-mud

I have screwed a new piece of drywall. Now I need to try to apply mud and finally paint. Should I clean, wash the old painted drywall first? If yes, how? It does not stand out in this picture but the old drywall is very dirty.

[image]

Comment: Unless it is greasy I just sand the area and then get dust free before mud and tape

Answer (score 1):

Clean with TSP.  You can use a sponge for the tsp.  I've used a big bucket and a bee mop.  You just need to be able apply some force while cleaning.  In your case that is a small area, a sponge is good.

https://www.homedepot.ca/product/t-s-p--trisodium-phosphate-powder-400-g/1000130976

Paint with primer.

Then tape and mud.

Comment: It's typical to mud, tape then prime and paint.

Comment: I have TSP already. Just use a sponge?

Comment: @brehma, yes if the wall is unpainted drywall.  If it is a gloss or semi-gloss paint drywall mud can have a hard time bonding.  I recommend clean and prime the painted service then mud.